# Zurb Foundation for Apps - CLI Fails

Tags: powershell, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use the new (as of 12/6/2014) foundation for apps CLI.

Setup:
Windows 8.1
Git, node (npm), JRuby (Ruby version for windows)

I ran windows powershell in administrator mode. It appears that the solution fails on the "bundler" step. I installed bundler (`gem install bundler`). This does not make sense to me. Do I need to install bundler globally somehow?

[image: Shell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same error come up.

I did some looking around at errors, and it seems that there is some sort of discrepancy between Nodejs and Windows. It seems to have something to do with the exex() call in the FoundationCLI.js file.

I did happen to find a work around that seems to be okay ( at least it lets the build finish ) and seems to run the app fine.

On line 97 in the FoundationCLI.js file change:

```
var bundleInstall = ["bundle"];
```

to:

```
var bundleInstall = ["bundle.bat"];
```

Like I said, it's a work around and I believe the guys at Zurb are looking in to the error already, but I found this to work for me so I could get an app started.

HTH.

Comment: Glad to know it's not just me. When I installed the CLI, it was through npm. How do I find that file to edit it?

Comment: I also installed in Windows via npm. Look at your error above on the terminal. The C:\Users\Alex\AppData\... follow that path all the way through and then go in to the file and change line 97. I've still not had any problems as of yet with this way of calling the new project.

Comment: This helped me find AppData (it was hidden) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/08/win8-howto-19-show-hidden-files-folders-and-drives.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

I had to run Ruby 1.9.3-p551 (any other version I ran into the inability to install gems due to an updated SSL certificate)

Then you need JRuby installed and it had to be version 1.7.15 (current is version 1.7.16.1, but this is not compatible with sass dependency)

Then be sure that you are using **specifically** sass version 3.4.7 
to check this:

```
gem list sass
```

to install

```
gem install sass -v "3.4.7"
```

My suggestion would be to uninstall all other versions of sass

Comment: Did you have any problems with an error like `gulp-ruby-sass: stderr : No such process - No such process`?