# Zurb Foundation for Apps - CLI Fails2

Tags: node.js, npm, zurb-foundation

At the risk of posting a duplicate, I am new here and don't have a rating yet so it wouldn't let me comment on the only relevant similar question I did find here:

Zurb Foundation for Apps - CLI Fails.

[Zurb Foundation for Apps - CLI Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334803/zurb-foundation-for-apps-cli-fails)

However I tried the answer there and I still get the same fail. 
My message is :
(I don't have a reputation so I can't post images "!@#"):

but it is essentially the same as the other post except mine mentions line 118 of foundationCLI.js where theirs notes line 139. Also the answer said to fix line 97 but in mine that code is on line 99.

```js
92 // NEW
93 // Clones the Foundation for Apps template and installs dependencies
94 module.exports.new = function(args, options) {
95 var projectName = args[0];
96  var gitClone = ['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps-template.git', args[0]];
97  var npmInstall = [npm, 'install'];
98  var bowerInstall = [bower, 'install'];
99  var bundleInstall = [bundle.bat];
100  if (isRoot()) bowerInstall.push('--allow-root');
101
102  // Show help screen if the user didn't enter a project name
103  if (typeof projectName === 'undefined') {
104    this.help('new');
105    process.exit();
106  }
107
108  yeti([
109    'Thanks for using Foundation for Apps!',
110    '-------------------------------------',
111    'Let\'s set up a new project.',
112    'It shouldn\'t take more than a minute.'
113  ]);
114
115   // Clone the template repo
116   process.stdout.write("\nDownloading the Foundation for Apps template...".cyan);
117   exec(gitClone, function(err, out, code) {
118    if (err instanceof Error) throw err;
119
120    process.stdout.write([
121      "\nDone downloading!".green,
122      "\n\nInstalling dependencies...".cyan,
123      "\n"
124    ].join(''));
```

I also posted an error log here

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7024

yesterday, as directed in the following error message: (which I am unable to post the image of "!@#").

But I have yet to receive a response there.

Any idea how I can get past this so I can start an app?

Thanks, A

Answer (score 0):

You may need to also install the `git` command-line client.  On line 117, the foundation-cli.js is trying to run `git clone` and this is failing.

Could you please run

git --version

and paste the text (not image) of the output you see?

If you have installed git already (e.g., because you have Github for Windows < https://windows.github.com/ > ) then you may need to use the `Git Shell` shortcut or close/re-open your command prompt window in order to use `git` on the command line.

Once you've installed git and closed/reopened your shell, try the command

`foundation-apps new myApp` again.

Comment: The output is 'git' is not recognized. I have github, gitbash and gitgui, but I see no git shell. How do I ensure they are all installed?

Comment: Update - Using Gitbash I successfully ran foundation-apps new pac under my (master) directory which is c:\vhosts  However I can't find the file or folder named pac and the command prompt told me to run foundation-apps watch and I got the error:

Comment: sorry accidently hit enter npm ERR! Error:ENOENT, open 'c:\vhosts\package.json' I then tried to change back the directory c:\Users\Amy and it wouldn't let me. So then I tried the same command in the Ruby prompt and got the same error.

Comment: I will have to try to reproduce this on my Windows machine -- won't be until tomorrow.  In the meantime if you are stuck perhaps you can get help on the Zurb IRC channel..